# Pass Bash argument in sqlite3 string command

Tags: bash, sqlite, parameter-passing

I have the following command which does not work:

```
sqlite3 my_db.sqlite "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';" | for i in $(cat) ; do sqlite3 my_db.sqlite 'SELECT * FROM "${i}"'; done
```

To explain it quickly: the first part below is supposed to retrieve the table names from a sqlite file that I have:

```
sqlite3 my_db.sqlite "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';"
```

And this part is supposed to display the entire content of each table recursivelyin the stdout:

```
for i in $(cat) ; do sqlite3 my_db.sqlite 'SELECT * FROM "${i}"'; done
```

The problem is that I have no idea how I am supposed to pass `i` to the sqlite command. I tried with `"${i}"` but obviously it is interpreted as a classic string to find a matching table name, and just return `Error: no such table: ${i}`

How should I pass `i` ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Piping to `for i in $(cat)` is an odd way to read from standard input into a variable. You'll much more often see something like `while read -r i; do ...`

Comment: This is a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen, even if you use the correct quotes.

Comment: @BenjaminW. using while instead of for is really improving the code or it is just a more traditional way to proceed.
I tried it with the while loop you wrote, it works also, but I don't really see any difference in the time of processing the speed is similar when I use the for loop.
If you can explain me I am always open to learn more things!

Comment: @chepner don't worry this code is not meant to be available online.

Comment: For starters, `$(cat)` creates a child process in every iteration, whereas `read` is a built-in. You're also subject to word splitting and glob expansion - if you have a table called `*`, it'll expand to all files in the current directory. Have a look at [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), which applies here.

Comment: @BenjaminW. ok good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use double quotes around the query to allow `bash` to recognize the variable. This implies that you have to correctly escape the double quotes that are part of the SQL statement:

```
... | for i ... ; do sqlite3 my_db.sqlite "SELECT * FROM \"${i}\""; done
```

Comment: Yes ! it works. I was close, I read that somewhere but unfortunately it was for MySQL so I thought it wouldn't work. Thank you for the help! I accept the answer as soon as I can.